# Graphene ID is created as Int but when Queried returns a string

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have a Model that has a ID of type Int.

```
class Contact(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'contact'
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : 'table'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    main_model_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table.main_model.id'))
    address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table.address.id'))
    unrelated_id = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    address = relationship(
        'Address',
        backref=backref('contacts', uselist=True),
        lazy='joined')
    product_release_location = relationship(
        MainModel,
        backref=backref('contact'),
        lazy='joined')
```

This(above address_id) is a foreign key to another table

```
class Address(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'address'
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : 'table'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(Text)
    county = Column(Text)
    state = Column(Text)
    country = Column(Text, nullable=False)
```

Both are Integers, however when i query the main model

```
query {
   MainModel {
        MainModelId
            contact {
                unrelated_id
                addressId
                address {
                    id
                    country
                    state
                }
             }
```

The Id returns a string: "QWRkcmVzczoxNA=="

```
{
    "MainModelId": "<a uuid>",
    "contact": [
      {
        "unrelated_id": "<a string>",
        "addressId": 14,
        "address": {
          "id": "QWRkcmVzczoxNA==",
          "country": "USA",
          "state": "Missouri"
        }
      }
    ],... <more returned here from extra in the query unrelated to this question>
```

This prevents me from performing a mutate that would update the contact and its related address by overwriting it.

Why does it have the Id in the address return a string while the contact Id returns an integer

Comment: Are you using Relay and graphene-django? I think it returns the "Relay ID" instead of the model ID but would be good to know more about your code, like the resolver, which server integrations is being used.

Comment: From what i've found it seems to be due to the fact that the keyword 'id' is taken by Graphene/ Graphql so it doesnt play well with the way our db schema is.

Answer (score 0):

As @KingDarBoja mentioned it, it looks like you are using Relay somewhere in your code. A Relay Node overrides the `id` field of your object and returns a base64 encoded string representing the type of your object and the id in form of `type:id`.

Decoding your id above (e.g. by using JavaScripts `atob` function) results in the following:

`atob("QWRkcmVzczoxNA==") => "Address:14"`

Please have a look at your `schema.py` and watch out for using the Relay Node interface in your model.

```
class AddressType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ...
        filter_fields = ...
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)  # <-- This extends your type
```